# Manual validation in Struts 2 on specific fields

Tags: java, validation, struts2, annotations

For example I have an `Action` Class called `UsersAction` where I have some methods like: `login`, `logout`, `register`, and so on.

And I have written `validate()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void validate() {
    if ("".equals(username)) {
        addFieldError("username", getText("username.required"));
    }
    if ("".equals(email)) {
        addFieldError("email", getText("email.required"));
    } else if (!Utils.isValidEmail(email)) {
        addFieldError("email", getText("invalid.email.address"));
    }
    if ("".equals(phone)) {
        addFieldError("phone", getText("phone.required"));
    }
    if ("".equals(password)) {
        addFieldError("password", getText("password.required"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that this solution works only when register action is called, anyway it wont work on login or logout cause it will check if the fields aren't null or email is correct and always will give an error. Okay, the solution for logout was to add `@SkipValidation` annotation above it, but I don't know how to tell to it that login have only 2 fields `username` and `password` and that it's not necessary to check `email` and `phone` too. I don't want to write an Action Class for each action in part, cause the purpose of Struts 2 is not this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `validateMethodName` methods, where `methodName` is the name of the method, e.g.,

```
validateLogin() { ... }
```

Otherwise provide some form of contextual information to  your `validate` method.

Comment: I tried with `validate_methodName` but it does not pass through it. What do you mean by `provide some form of contextual information to your validate method.`?

Comment: @Ferrago Sorry, it's `validateLogin`. Why not switch to XML for the simple validation, though?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Because I needed a faster solution, xml is more time consumer I think, don't you think? anyway before that I not used any framework to validate (just some manual "validations"), I began using Validation Framework recently so I don't have so much experience with it

Comment: @Ferrago I'm ambivalent regarding which is better/worse. The nice thing about the simple XML validations is that they can be used to drive client-side validation as well, although not all validators are supported by default.

Comment: And if JS is disabled on the client side?

Comment: @Ferrago Then obviously it wouldn't work? Validation has to happen on the server side *anyway*--but most people don't have JS turned off these days because it would lead to horrible UX.

Answer (score 2):

Using annotations, annotate your action method `login` with

```
@Action(value="login", results = {
  @Result(name="input", location = "/login.jsp")
},interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}))
@Validations(requiredFields = {
  @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, fieldName = "username", message = "${getText("username.required")}"),
  @RequiredFieldValidator(type = ValidatorType.FIELD, fieldName = "password", message = "${getText("password.required")}")
})
```

it will only validate `username` and `passsword` fields. Similar do the other action methods.

**References:**

- [Convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention)
- [Validation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html)
- [Validatin annotation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-annotation.html)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using Annotations at all, @SkipValidation parameter is for xml based configuration

Comment: You are mistaken, It is not a parameter, it is an annotation.

Comment: Ok then thanks, but anyway I'm not using annotation based configuration, but xml based.

Comment: Ok I will give you the references that will help you to rewrite it in xml.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your time, anyway @Dave Newton's answer was the best for me, I appreciate your help